# Kbd does not format correctly for < (less than) and > (greater than)

Tags: support, markdown, kbd

Sometimes the less than and greater than keys are important, especially in gaming.  Unfortunately markdown doesn't seem to agree.  It renders the code `<kbd><</kbd>` as just <kbd><</kbd>.  When it's formatting properly it renders like so: <kbd>a</kbd>.  See ["Building a stairwell down multiple levels"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/building-a-stairwell-down-multiple-levels-in-dwarf-fortress/1270#1270) for a real example.

Comment: Does it act like it's going to work in the preview area?  I don't have access to gaming yet, but it seems to be working on webapps.  The only site I can't get it to work is here on meta, where it was disabled.

Comment: It looks like it works on Pro Webmasters also, so I would think it would work on Gaming also.

Comment: @Bill It works for most characters, just not the `<` and `>`.  Preview shows the same.  Sorry you're not in gaming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the HTML encoded version, since that's the beginning and ending of a HTML tag, and we support (whitelisted) HTML in posts per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Like so:

<kbd>></kbd>
<kbd><</kbd>

```
<kbd>&gt;</kbd>  
<kbd>&lt;</kbd>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, at least on my gaming post.  It still shows up as a `<` without the key formatting.

Comment: @c.ross you had spelling errors in your tags. It is correct and it does work.